# AngularJS Karma expectGet Unit Test Failing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

```
navsearchService.getNewsData(scope)
                .then(function (response) {
                    expect(response).toBeTruthy();
                });

            $httpBackend.expectGET(/.*\/news\/search\/apple/).respond(200, mock);
            $httpBackend.flush();
```

I have the above unit test I'm trying to get working but I get the following error in Terminal

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) app.navsearch navSearch should getNewsData FAILED
    Error: Unexpected request: GET https://domain.com/news/search?search=apple
    Expected GET /.*\/news\/search\/apple/
```

Could someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction and get this working?

Comment: Your regex doesn't match your URL, that might be an issue? Does it work if you just use the URL instead of a regex?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't match your URL. Try changing it to this:

`/.*\/news\/search\?search=apple/`